# Unable to find uuid:xxxxx:Metadata using Java

Tags: core-service, content-manager

I am new to SDL Tridion sdl, and we are using SDL Tridion 2011. While trying to create a new Component, I am getting an exception saying:

> Unable to find uuid:xxxxxxx:Metadata.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to create the Component (assuming you are doing it through code)?

Comment: In Web 8.5 I also found out that the issue appears when you create a new Component in the TCM following these steps: 1. Create a new Component 2. Select a Schema that has the Metadata tab 3. Select a different Schema without a Metadata tab 4. Fill in all required fields 5. Try to save the Component The error occurs as the UI obviously do not recognize properly that there is no Metadata after selecting the second Schema.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is common when a schema on which the component is based on has changed.  In your case, it looks like there is a metadata schema nested within the component's schema, but it's namespace has changed.

So what you would need to do is work with your Tridion technical team to revert the underlying metadata schema namespace, or update the component schema to refer to the new metadata schema within.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error, I am assuming that your code is working with particular UUID in one environment and not working in other environment. Because that is the only way you will have UUID part of the code.

If that is the case then the issue is with schema creation:

> When you create new schema then new UUID is generated for that schema
>   and if you content port the schema then UUID from source environment
>   is carried forward to destination.

So solution in your situation is to content port the schema having issues from the environment where you code is working to the environment where your code is breaking.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered this issue.

In my case, the schema for a component had been updated -- in particular, some metadata field names were *changed*.

It seems that XPM doesn't quite "check out" a component in the same way that the regular editor does. The result is that a schema field has content, but it's stored in a field name that doesn't exist.

I was able to resolve the issue by opening the component in the CME (*not* XPM), checking it out, and then checking it in.

Answer (score 1):

If your CM is SDL Web 8.5, then try hotfix CME_8.5.0.4578

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error while using the `CME`. It turned out the problem was what Arthur N. explained in his comment. The folder where I was creating the component had a linked schema (not mandatory). This linked schema had metadata, but I was switching to a different schema that did not have metadata.

I just removed the linked schema from the folder, then remade my component and selected the schema I wanted straight off the bat. No error when I saved it that time.